# Алгоритм соединения бинарных деревьев поиска

Tags: алгоритм

Даны два независимых друг от друга бинарных дерева поиска, какими способами ветви этих деревьев можно соединить в одно ?

Comment: Свои мысли есть?

Comment: Если из первого дерева взять узел и вставить его во второе, то надо будет вставлять на один узел меньше. Это даст алгоритм со сложностью *NlogN*. Можно ли сделать то же за линейное время? Кажется да, но алгоритм будет немного сложнее.

Comment: да сделать список из каждого дерева, слить оба списка за линейно и построить дерево из сорт списка=) будет O(N+M)